# get all recent job failures in Autosys

Tags: autosys

What's a command to list all recent failures in Autosys?

I was thinking of `autorep -d -J ALL` followed by some kind of `grep`, but the `autorep` report comes in paragraphs, with the job name and the status in separate lines, so I need to write a custom filter in Perl unless I'm overlooking some quick and simple option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-d` flag is giving details, which is why `autorep` is producing paragraph-like output. Running `autorep -J ALL | grep "FA"` or similar should give you the listing just fine.

Comment: Good point.  Although the `grep "FA"` gives a few spurious hits (successful jobs with FA in their name).  Because of that, and also because I like the details the -d flag gives me, I may end up writing that Perl filter one of these days.

Comment: Narveson - Should never put 'FA' (or RU/AC/IN/OI/OH) in the job name.

Comment: `grep -w FA` will solve the problem of jobs containing 'FA', unless you have a job *called* FA.

Answer (score 3):

Use spaces in the search of the output of autorep for failed jobs, i.e. `grep " FA "`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say all your jobs start with a common database prefix.

```
CRANE_job1
CRANE_job2
```

and so on..

Use:

```
aj CR% |grep -w FA
```